# How do I use recylerview adapter to choose different view for each activity

Tags: android-studio

How do I use 1 Recyclerview adapter for different activities with different views?

I am using android studio 3.1

```
@Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        if(viewType == 0) {
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_program, parent, false);

            return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
        }else{
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_exercise, parent, false);

            return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.image.setImageResource(exerciseList.get(position).getImage_id());
        holder.text.setText(exerciseList.get(position).getName());

        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                //Call to new activity
                if(true) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewExercise.class);
                    intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.putExtra("image_id", exerciseList.get(position).getImage_id());
                    intent.putExtra("name", exerciseList.get(position).getName());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, listOfExercises.class);
                    intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.putExtra("image_id", exerciseList.get(position).getImage_id());
                    intent.putExtra("name", exerciseList.get(position).getName());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
                    }
        });
    }
```

when I click an item on the view Holder, only 1 view type displays for different activities. Please see attached images
[Programs.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7BN6.png)
[listOfExercises.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV3Qs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the below Override method..

```
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {}
```

Comment: Hi Shameem, I have attached desired result which I am still unable to achieve. please note that I am a new to computer programming.

Comment: Could you please see the example https://medium.com/better-programming/create-heterogeneous-views-using-recyclerview-in-android-e2ad626686f6